# AsyncFunction: message error in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I have the following code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    execute (message) {
        console.log(message)
        message.channel.send('Pong')
    }
}
```

However I keep getting the error: `cannot read channel of undefined`. When I log `message` to the console it returns `[AsyncFunction: message]`.

The event listener:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.on('message', (message) => require('./message.js')(message, client));
```

message.js:

```js
module.exports = (message, client) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.channel.id === configFile.PollChannel || message.channel.id === configFile.MemesChannel)
    require('../commands/reactions.js')(message);
  else {
    if (message.guild) {
      require('../backend/deletingMessages.js')(message, client);
      require('../backend/levelling.js')(message, client);
      //require('../commands/counting.js').execute(message, client);
      //require('../commands/talk2billy')(message);
      require('../commands/mentions/mentions.js')(message, client);
      require('../commands/ping.js').execute(message);
    } else {
      require('../backend/dmRecieving.js')(message, client);
    }
  }
}
```

I am only getting this error in the `ping.js` file.

---

Comment: Heads up: Your code looks like it triggers other files, you might want to add some `if else` blocks or a command handler so all the files won't trigger. 

Your code looks ok, is there anything else that triggers `message.js`?

Comment: No, only the event listener file.

Comment: whole error please

Comment: @Apachedev is right, please include the full error to know where exactly it is taking place.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten `:` after the word `execute`

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    execute: (message) {
        console.log(message)
        message.channel.send('Pong')
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!